# Hide and show HTML Select Options

Tags: php, html, css

I'm writing a registration page in with PHP:

```
<form action="" method="post">
            <input type="text" id="lname" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" required>
            <input style='margin:8px;'type="text" id="fname" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" required>
            <br>
            <br>
            <input type="emailtext" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" required>
            <br>
            <div class="selectdiv" required>
                <p class="boldlabel">I am a</p>

                <input type="radio" id="tutor" name="tutororstudent" value="tutor" required>
                <label for="tutor">Tutor</label><br>

                <input type="radio" id="student" name="tutororstudent" value="student">
                <label for="student">Student</label><br>

                <div class="innerdiv">
                    <p class="boldlabel">Grade level</p>
                    <select name="grade">
                      <option value="1">1st Grade</option>
                      <option value="2">2nd Grade</option>
                      <option value="3">3rd Grade</option>
                      <option value="4">4th grade</option>
                      <option value="5">5th Grade</option>
                      <option value="6">6th Grade</option>
                      <option value="7">7th Grade</option>
                      <option value="8">8th grade</option>
                      <option value="9">9th Grade</option>
                      <option value="10">10th Grade</option>
                      <option value="11">11th Grade</option>
                      <option value="12">12th grade</option>
                      <option value="13">Undergrad/grad</option>
                      <option value="14">Post College</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <input style='margin:16px;'type="password" id="pwd" name="pwd" placeholder="Password" required>
            <input type="submit" value="Register">
   </form>
```

I want the div "innerdiv" to only show up if the user selects the student radio button. How do I do this in PHP? How do I hide it until the user selects the student radio button?

Comment: You can't do it in PHP. PHP runs on the server, not the client. You need to use JavaScript or jQuery

Comment: Well, php does have echo "<script></script>". Could I do it with that?

Comment: Also, I can use <script> tags without echoing them.

Comment: You could output a script between those tags that put an event handler onto the student radio button; the handler would then make innerdiv visible dependent on the state of the radio button.

Comment: _"php does have echo "<script></script>""_ ...yes, that just tells PHP to output some script tags. That's the place where you'd write some Javacript, between those tags. Remember that PHP's job is just to output stuff which gets sent to the browser. So if you output Javascript, then the browser will execute that javascript when it receives it. But ultimately, anything you write in between those script tags is Javascript, not PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You only can achieve that using javascript:
add id to your innerdiv.

```
            <div class="innerdiv" id="innerdiv" style="display:none">
                <p class="boldlabel">Grade level</p>
                <select name="grade">
                  <option value="1">1st Grade</option>
                  <option value="2">2nd Grade</option>
                  <option value="3">3rd Grade</option>
                  <option value="4">4th grade</option>
                  <option value="5">5th Grade</option>
                  <option value="6">6th Grade</option>
                  <option value="7">7th Grade</option>
                  <option value="8">8th grade</option>
                  <option value="9">9th Grade</option>
                  <option value="10">10th Grade</option>
                  <option value="11">11th Grade</option>
                  <option value="12">12th grade</option>
                  <option value="13">Undergrad/grad</option>
                  <option value="14">Post College</option>
                </select>
            </div>
```

bottom of your page, put this:

```
<script>
    let student = document.getElementById('student');
    student.addEventListener('click', display);
    let tutor = document.getElementById('tutor');
    tutor.addEventListener('click', () => div.style.display = "none");


    let div = document.getElementById('innerdiv');

    function display(){
        if(student.checked) {
            div.style.display = "block";
         }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: And I would have set the div originally to have `display: none;` correct? EDIT: Oh, I just saw the in-line style.

Comment: Your event handler is not correct. `div` will never be `checked`

Comment: @mistertwst try again. i wrongly wrote the expression.

Comment: How do I make it go away if I change the radio button to the other option?

Comment: i'd recommend swapping the event listener from "click" to "change", as that would be more accurately suited to the purpose of the event listener.